# For all sets $A$ and $B$, if $A \cap B = \emptyset$ then $A \times B = \emptyset$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I'm having trouble understanding how I should go about this problem. Any explanation or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did the instructions for this problem say "prove or disprove"?

Comment: Um, you should say the problem is obviously not true.  Let $A = \{1,2,3\}$ and $B=\{a,b,c\}$ then $A\cap B = \emptyset$  and $A\times B = \{(1,a)(1,b)(1,c),(2,a),(2,b),(2,c)(3,a),(3,b),(3,c)\}$ which is not empty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The statement is not true.

For example let $A=\{ 0\} $ and $B= \{ 1 \}$.

The intersection is empty but $A \times B = \{ (0,1) \}$